# GSuite Out of Office Calendar Script not parsing all users?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-workspace

I setup an app script from this help file: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/vacation-calendar

The default Access setting for users in our domain is to "See all Events" for all domain users - but when I run the sync, it runs without error - picks up only one users event and it doesn't pick up my test 'out of office' event I created.

Does this script need additional perms or do I need to change my sharing settings - I dont know.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - so I'm just going to close this particular issue. The script parses a Google Group, I was using the "all hands" special team alias in the group, which does not break out the individual users. I'm going to try and change the script to use the Directory API instead.